# R Comparing Two Data Frames without using Merge

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to compare two data frames with same structure of columns (in terms of number of columns and column names). If the value in a cell of the column A of the data frame X matches with the value in a cell of the column A of the data frame Y, the values in the cells (in the same row) of the column B and C of the data frame X will be changed to the values in the cells of the column B and C of the data frame Y. For example,

**Data**

```
df_X <- structure(list(A = c("Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Banana"), 
    B = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), C = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), D = c(2L, 2L, 
    3L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df_Y <- structure(list(A = c("Apple", "Banana."), B = c(4L, 2L), C = c(3L, 
3L), D = c(2L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

Data Frame X
A          B  C  D
Apple      1  2  2
Banana     2  2  2
Orange     3  3  3
Banana     2  1  5

Data Frame Y
A         B  C  D
Apple     4  3  2
Banana.   2  3  4
```

After Matching, data frame x will become:

```
Data Frame X
A          B  C  D
Apple      4  3  2
Banana     2  3  2
Orange     3  3  3
Banana     2  3  5
```

I know merging the two data frames cab probably do the trick. But I wonder can I achieve the task without using merge/left_join() (in dplyr)? Because my data frame is really long (lots of columns) and I want an independent data frame X in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` to overwrite matching rows from `x` with `y`.

```
i <- match(x$A, y$A)
j <- !is.na(i)
x[j,c("B","C")] <- y[i[j],c("B","C")]
#       A B C D
#1  Apple 4 3 2
#2 Banana 2 3 2
#3 Orange 3 3 3
#4 Banana 2 3 5
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
A          B  C  D
Apple      1  2  2
Banana     2  2  2
Orange     3  3  3
Banana     2  1  5")
y <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
A         B  C  D
Apple     4  3  2
Banana    2  3  4")
```

Comment: Thanks fir your reply! However, when I try the last line of your code, it shows "Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2". Do you know why that happens?

Comment: Do you have a `list`?